# Colocar StringRequest/JSONRequest de Volley dentro de una clase para ser llamado

Tags: android

Quisiera preguntar sobre cómo colocar un StringRequest dentro de una clase, porque suele mostrar un error mostrando que necesita un Context para poder trabajar. No me parece pedir como parámetro un Context context. Poder llamar a una clase que haga el trabajo y devolver un JSON, para asi poder trabajarlo, sin tener que repetir código.

```
StringRequest sRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String respuesta) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, respuesta, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mostrarDatos(respuesta);
                    //textViewMuestra.setText(respuesta);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("dni", sDni);
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue colaSolicitudes = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    colaSolicitudes.add(sRequest);}
```

Comment: En mi caso, creé un singleton para gestionar las peticiones con Volley. Sin embargo, el Context tienes que utilizarlo igualmente. Los dos métodos principales que utilizo son `public static ClaseControladorVolley getInstance(Context ctx)` para obtener la instancia y `public void addToRequestQueue(Request req)` para agregar una solicitud HTTP.

Comment: Agrega el error  que se muestra en el LogCat, para saber exactamente que sucede.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, en tu Singleton como parametro le envias el Context pero cuando tu haces una llamada tienes que tener claro donde estas. Si estas en una actividad utilizas el `this` pero si estas dentro un fragment lo obtienes el contexto con `getACtivity()`

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema es como estas definiendo tu StringRequest, el metodo `getParams()` esta fuera de lugar, deberia ser de esta forma

```
StringRequest sRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String respuesta) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, respuesta, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mostrarDatos(respuesta);
                    //textViewMuestra.setText(respuesta);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
});


/*            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("dni", sDni);
            return params;
        } 
};*/
```

Aqui tienes la documentacion con un ejemplo
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

En cuanto a tu `RequestQueue` es correcto, usas `this`, haciendo referencia a la Activity, si estas dentro de un Activity,

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

si te encuentras en un Fragment usa `getActivity()` como contexto.

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
```